# Is toString() JavaScript output "guaranteed" to be the same in every browser/implementation?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using a specific framework and somewhere in my code I have a function as a parameter.

I want to check if that function is a specific anonymous function out of that framework. I don't have access to the original function itself to have a proper reference.

I'm creating some debugging tools for myself (non-production) and I'd like to check if the value of `func.toString()` is:

`function(){return undefined }`

... to check if it's this specific function and handle some special case.

**Question**

Is `toString()` JavaScript output sort of "guaranteed" to be the same in every browser/implementation? Or could it be that other browsers i.e. format it different, remove unnecessary spaces or maybe don't return the output at all?

**Note**

I know these are in any normal circumstances terrible practices, but this will be in debug tools that only I or the people in my team will use. In theory we also control the Browser we use but I am more interested from a theoretical point of view.

**The code**

Not necessary for the question, but to give more context.

The code is a knockout.js debug bindingHandler where I can easily see what context an `element` is.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.debug = 
{
    init: function(element:HTMLElement, valueAccessor:Action, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext:KnockoutBindingContext) 
    {
        let value = valueAccessor();

        // only "real way" to check for undefined, if the propery itself would be undefined
        // the normal use of valueAcessor() would also return undefined, so we can't differentiate between
        // an unexisting property or deliberately leaving out the property
        if ( valueAccessor.toString() == 'function(){return undefined }' )
            value = bindingContext.$data;

        console.log( '----- Knockoutbinding -----' );
        console.log( element );
        console.log( value );
        console.log( '---------------------------' );
    }
};
```

Useage:

```
<div data-bind="debug: window.innerHeight">          <!-- 450 -->
<div data-bind="debug: window.nonExistingProperty">  <!-- undefined -->
<div data-bind="debug: $data"></div>                 <!-- current context -->
<div data-bind="debug"></div>                        <!-- current context (new) -->
```

**Update**

I just did some simple tests and Chrome, Firefox and Edge at least seem to honor the exact same source code like @jabaa mentions.

Comment: If you want to do this for debugging, better inject some code into the framework that enables you to identify this function (by something else than its code representation)

Comment: This is more a "nice to have" then something critical. I prefer if something breaks/differentiates from the original it's this script, not the original framework  I added an example to clear it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since ES2018, the spec requires the return value of `toString()` to be the exact same source code as it was declared, including any whitespace and/or comments — or, if the host doesn't have the source code available for some reason, requires returning a native function string. Support for this revised behavior can be found in the compatibility table.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString

If I correctly understand, all browsers and runtime environments have to return the same string since 2018.

**Is toString() JavaScript output "guaranteed" to be the same in every browser/implementation?"*

Yes, since 2018.

Comment: wow, that a suprise plot twist, I already accepted the other answer. How can it be that it not mentioned here: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.tostring

Comment: @DirkBoer but it is mentioned, right in step 2: "*If HostHasSourceTextAvailable(func) is true, then return CodePointsToString(func.[[SourceText]])*"

Answer (score 2):

The `Function.prototype.toString` function is part of the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.tostring), but it's not strict enough to guarantee that full string comparison (like you do) will work.

The only thing that is enforced by the specification is that the output is a valid string representation of a [`NativeFunction`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-NativeFunction) so two implementations could comply with this specification while outputting different strings (e.g: different indentation, carriage returns, etc.)